# How to auto insert parent id into another table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a two table named `applicants` and `jobs`. I am using **Laravel 5.2**.

**jobs table:**

```
id | job_tittle | email         |...
-----------------------------  
1  | Engineer   | info@mail.com |...
```

**applicants table:**

```
id | job_id | name |...
-----------------------------  
1  |   1    | john |...
```

Now i want when anyone submit the application form against a job then job_id is auto inserted in the `applicants` table.

I have tried so far **ApplicantController:**

```
$jobAll = Job::all();
$jobId = Job::find($jobAll->first()->id);
//$jobId = $jobAll->first()->id;

DB::table('applicants')->insert([
'job_id' => $jobId,
]);
```

But its not working.Could anyone tell me how can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this:

```
$jobAll = Job::all();

 $jobId = $jobAll->first()->id;


 DB::table('applicants')->insert([
   'job_id' => $jobId,
 ]);
```

**UPDATE**

```
//Insert for all data
 $apllicantsId = DB::table('applicants')->insertGetId([
   'name' => $name,
   ......
 ]);

 $jobAll = Job::all();

 $jobId = $jobAll->first()->id;

//insert job id
 DB::table('applicants')
 ->where('id',$apllicantsId)
 ->Update([
   'job_id' => $jobId,
 ]);
```

**OR**

```
 $jobAll = Job::all();

 $jobId = $jobAll->first()->id;

 //Insert for all data with job id
 $apllicantsId = DB::table('applicants')->insertGetId([
   'job_id' => $jobId,
   'name' => $name,
   ......
 ]);
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Its working but it is inserting two row at one insert one is job_id with all blank data and another is all data without job_id. http://prntscr.com/dwms0o

Comment: again every time its insert same `job_id` (1) though i was applying different job.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud: Ok, See my *UPDATE*

Comment: its solve double inserting data but do not solve same `job_id` insertation. It s have many job post ( http://prntscr.com/dwn2j1 ) when i applying then it should insert `job_id` for which job i applying.I pass job_id `http://localhost/NoticeBoard/public/career/apply/1`

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud: Please provide `route` for store applicants data with job id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$job = Job::find($id);
$jodId = $job->id;

DB::table('applicants')->insert([
'job_id' => $jobId,
]);
```

Comment: its giving me undefined variable `id`.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud  `$jobAll->first()->id`  will give you the first id!  e.g.  `1`,  you should have your id before saving to `applicants`

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
$job = Job::find($id);
DB::table('applicants')->insert(['job_id' => $job->id]);
```

When you're using Eloquent, you could [define a relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) in the `Job` model:

```
public function applicants()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Applicant');
}
```

And then use it when creating an applicant:

```
$job = Job::find($id);
$job->applicants()->create($applicantData);
```

**Update**
You've shown the `store()` method in comments, so in this case instead of using `DB::insert()` do this:

```
$job = Job::find($id);
$applicant['job_id'] = $job->id;
```

Comment: First solution is giving me undefind variable `id`.This is the method in `ApplicantController`  http://pastebin.com/2FV7kKDf

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud please look at the **Update** part of my answer.

Comment: It is same `undefined variable id`.Remember i have given `ApplicantController` store function.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud `$id` is an ID of a job. You should pass it from the form or another method. Think about it. You really need to know what exactly job applicant applies to, right?